# How can I export sub-directories to a specified depth greater than "immediate children" and less than "fully recursive" using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to export an SVN path `\A\B\C` to a local folder `Z:\Local\`.

`C` contains the directory structure `D\E\F`. I don't want to export the sub-directories inside the `F` folder, only the files that are immediate children of `F`.

How can I do this using TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN allows you to make [sparse checkouts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth), meaning you only check out a subset of the repository contents. You can do this by clicking the <kbd>Choose Items...</kbd> button in the Checkout dialog and selecting only the items you want.

I don't think you can do this for exports, so if you really want a clean directory tree, you'll need to follow a two-step process. First, do a sparse checkout, then either:

1. Delete the `.svn` directory from the root of the working copy to remove it from version control
2. Export the working copy directory onto itself
3. Export the working copy directory to another location in the filesystem

See the [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html) for details.

Comment: @bahrep I'm not sure what point you're trying to make with your comment.

Comment: The link leads to the original doc about sparse dirs.

Comment: @bahrep The OP is using TortoiseSVN, so I think linking to the Tortoise docs makes more sense. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: For in-depth description of the feature it makes sense to read SVNBook. BTW, I think that using sparse checkout from command prompt may be more convenient than via TortoiseSVN. :)